# Get mount point from ID from lsusb

Tags: lsusb

From the output of lsusb, how to get the mount point of a specific usb device from its ID?
For examples, output of lsub:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0781:5567 San Disk Corp. Cruzer Blade
```

Comment: Technically you won't, because the "id" represents vendor and model and is not unique. You wouldn't be able to distinguish two identical USB devices by this "id".

Comment: Agree! In the kernel output, you can see where the system connected a USB device with a specific ID (dmesg command).